# Capture caller line number at scope exit

Tags: c++, c++17

I am working on a RAII class that should be able to trace the code-flow of a function. It should be able to capture the line number of the function when it is constructed and do the same when it is destructed. The macros `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` would not work since they are substituted at the time of call. This rules out the following approach:

```
#define PRINT_LINES                            \
struct LineRecorder                            \
{                                              \
   LineRecorder() { std::cout << __LINE__; }   \
   ~LineRecorder() { std::cout << __LINE__; }  \ <- Substitutes the line number at macro call
} {};
```

C++20 has support for source location which works at compile-time. This led me to the approach:

```
struct LineRecorder
{
  LineRecorder(std::source_location location = std::source_location::current())
  {
    std::cout << location.line();
  }
  ~LineRecorder(std::source_location location = std::source_location::current()) 
   // destructor can't take any arguments (not even default ones)
  {
    std::cout << location.line();
  }
};
```

Some other approaches that didn't pan out:

- Since source_location.current is marked constexpr, it should be evaluated before any inlining is done: that rules out any lambda trickery I could think of.
- I plan to use it inside performance sensitive code, so should ideally not add any run-time overhead: this rules out stacktrace parsing. The std::cout in the code above is just a (very very) expensive placeholder.

Is there any way this can be achieved?

Comment: Oh that's just example code. These numbers get added to an in-place constructed struct and dumped to a file in another thread that isn't performance sensitive.

Comment: The cost of the above process is 2 integer copies (if the code doesn't get inlined) - one to copy it into the function that processes these numbers and another to copy it into the struct itself. This is an acceptable overhead.

Comment: As the destructor isn't explicitly called i don't think there is any way to get the line number where it is triggered as there isn't really a line

Comment: Just use `libunwind`, it won't ever get easier than that...

Answer (score 1):

You can’t do this: the main reason is that `~T` can be called from **many places** other than the `}` of a block.  Among those are various parts of the constructor of any type that contains a subobject of type `T`, any evaluation that might throw out of a block that contains a local `T` variable, a `new T[n]` expression (for `n>1`), or the end of a thread or process.  C++20 adds `coroutine_handle::destroy` as an indirect means of causing destruction.

None of these have a good “What line is this?” answer.  The fact that our syntactic trick of a default argument (which is a bit silly anyway) doesn’t work is at most a corollary.

Comment: Yeah. I was thinking along the same lines. Just wondered if there could be anything that I was missing.